# Animating transition with a slide up

Tags: android, translate-animation

I'm trying to create an animation that I use with an overridePendingTransition() method. However I can't get the result I want. I want the first activity to slide up out of the screen and the second activity coming in from the bottom. The bottom animation works, but I can't get the first activity to slide up. Currently I use this animation:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
 </set>
```

But this just makes it slide down to the bottom of the screen, I've tried a lot of value combinations but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

here interpolator :  An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate) to be accelerated, decelerated, repeated, etc.

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html)

Answer (score 1):

To slide up, Use

```
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
```

and

```
android:toYDelta="-100%p"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

use this it's working fine